# DNS request sample traffic

Tags: data-request, internet

I am trying to find a dataset about DNS request, which is created by any group of users during a period (a week or a month...).

For example: employers in a selected company used the internet and made some DNS requests, then there is a collector which capturing all of them.

Because what I really care is the DNS requests and their created time. Therefore, if information like source IP address or requested domain name... is missing, it is still OK.

I wonder if there is any kind of dataset now. I have tried to find but still, there is no satisfied collection.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can do such capturing yourself using Wireshark filter out the DNS port data

and then you can retrieve it to a file use it as you like
[here](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
Actually, We have considered this method to capture the DNS traffic for ourselves. However, the problem is the data we could capture is not good enough as I think because there are only a few devices in our environment. We also want good quality data to evaluate our modeling method, so I wrote this question.

Comment: in that case, I would prefer some advice go to your isp and ask their manager about your request because a lot of isp has their DNS logs for over a month as you mentioned you don't need IP address to be there they will than willing to help you if you know them well.be careful privacy breach is illigal